# incoming mail with low score, but count as spam?

Tags: centos, spamassassin, mailscanner

my Centos server currently running spamassassin to filter spam email, it work together with mailscanner, it work fine before but suddently got a problem:

```
Nov 15 16:12:02 main MailScanner[4079]: Message A6D3969B8200.AE900 from x.x.x.x (someone@somedomain.com) to myemail.com is spam, SORBS-SPAM, SpamAssassin (not cached, score=2.797, required 4.5, HTML_MESSAGE 0.00, MIME_BASE64_TEXT 2.80)
```

The spam threshold score was 4.5, however, some messages judge as spam even it score is under 4.5 (like example above), could someone told me what happen??

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Seems SORBS is reacting to the mail. Check with http://www.sorbs.net/lookup.shtml

Comment: Thanks, I will give a try!! But i have the same problem even I use spamhaus-ZEN , this strange problem still occurs...

Comment: I think what the comment above is trying to tell you is that it's the SORBS failure that's made **MailScanner** decide this is spam, even though **SpamAssassin** has cleared it.  MailScanner uses more than just the SA score to decide whether something is spam or not.  If you don't want that, don't use MailScanner; just have your MDA invoke SA directly, and classify accordingly.